# Customising Moodle

Tags: moodle, moodle-api

I am using Moodle LMS Management system for our project. We have different roles in the project like a principal, admin, tutor, course creator, student, IQA, EQA. The problem we are facing is, restricting the comment section. See, Tutor will give feedback on a student assignment and submission.

So if the tutor comments, all the other roles can see the comment. If IQA person gives feedback on particular student submission means, that comment should be visible only to principal, tutor, admin, EQA. It should not be visible to the student. My doubt is, how to restrict the comments in moodle?  Any Help Appreciated..

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i tried totally in out of the box. like going to users----> permissions-------> define roles.. I tried to change there. but nothing worked out..

Comment: There are a lot of predefined moodle files. I am not sure, where to change the code. Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: Have you written any code you can share which reproduces this problem?

Comment: I'm not really sure if you are even asking a coding question or if this is a software question ....

Comment: Actually it's a coding question. Once if you download Moodle framework code and put it in var/www/html, and do some configurations means your LMS system will be built. We will get a lot of PHP files in this folder. My problem is, not able to figure it out how to change and where to change the code. Because it's a pre-defined code from moodle.

Comment: This makes sense!  Thank you for the clarification.  And good luck!

Comment: Do you have any idea.